# Square pictures as symbols

Tags: matrices

I have some square pictures in eps format which should be regarded as 
mathematical symbols. Each square picture consists of a blank square with some drawing in the center. I would like to be able to do essentially two things with these pictures.

1. **(Most important)** Make matrices out of these pictures. Problem: I need the final matrix to be a square. The lines dividing each column and each row of the matrix must match precisely the borders of the square pictures. The result that I get using the array matrix is not satisfactory because the final matrix is not really a square, and the lines dividing columns and lines do not match borders of pictures.
2. **(Also important)** I need to write sequences of these pictures, enclosed into several types of brackets, such as (),[],{} , and such that 
   the pictures are separated by commas. The result I get is not satisfactory because for some reason I get huge spaces under the pictures.

For instance, the following is an example of square picture. 
[image: An example of Square Picture.]

Below, it is an example of the things I would like to do with square pictures.

[image: The results I would like to get.]

But what I actually get with the minimal example given below is the following, which is unsatisfactory.

[image: The Results I get with the code below.]

A minimal example of my code is given below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\squarepicture}{{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{squarepicture.eps}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\{ \squarepicture, \squarepicture, \squarepicture  \right\}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left( \squarepicture, \squarepicture, \squarepicture  \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\squarepicture & \squarepicture & \squarepicture \\
\hline
\squarepicture & \squarepicture & \squarepicture \\
\hline
\squarepicture & \squarepicture & \squarepicture \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the symbol to be slightly moved down, with `\vcenter`. I'd avoid `scaled`, and favor setting `height`, so the symbol with scale along with the current font size.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\squarepicture}{%
  \ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{%
    \includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`A]{squarepicture}%
  }}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\{ \squarepicture, \squarepicture, \squarepicture \}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
( \squarepicture, \squarepicture, \squarepicture )
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{array}{@{\vline}c@{\vline}c@{\vline}c@{\vline}}
\hline
\squarepicture & \squarepicture & \squarepicture \\
\hline
\squarepicture & \squarepicture & \squarepicture \\
\hline
\squarepicture & \squarepicture & \squarepicture \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\Huge
\begin{equation}
\{ \squarepicture, \squarepicture, \squarepicture \}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, this is the Metapost source for the picture:

```
beginfig(1);
fill (0,0)--(100,0)--(100,100)--(0,100)--cycle withcolor (1,1,0);
pickup pencircle scaled 4;
draw fullcircle scaled 90 shifted (50,50);
draw (5,50)--(95,50);
draw (50,5)--(50,95);
pickup pencircle scaled 10;
drawdot (30,70);
drawdot (70,30);
endfig;

end.
```

Comment: What about using [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) with the `export` option, and then `valign=c`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The resulting matrix is precisely what I need. The brackets are also nice.

Comment: @Werner ``\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`A]{squarepicture}\end{tabular}`` is package free.

Answer (score 3):

I propose another solution for the vertical alignment problem. A macro that vertically adjusts the argument to get the correct delimiters. For the array, egreg solution seems good.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\squarepicture
  {\tikz[scale=.5]{\fill[yellow](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
     \draw circle(.8)(0,.8)--(0,-.8)(.8,0)--(-.8,0)
           (.35,-.35)circle(.1)(-.35,.35)circle(.1);}}

\newcommand*\adjustheight[1]{\mathpalette\doadjustheight{#1}}
\newcommand*\doadjustheight[2]
  {\ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{$#1#2$}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\{ \adjustheight{\squarepicture, \squarepicture, \squarepicture} \right\}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left( \adjustheight{\squarepicture, \squarepicture, \squarepicture} \right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If you prefer a more LaTeXy definition you can use

```
\newcommand*\doadjustheight[2]
  {\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+\fontdimen22\textfont2}{$#1#2$}}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this is a nice refinement. I accepted egreg's answer since the matrix was the most important.